# Exception raises a TypeError

Tags: python, try-except

I've a question about try-exception statements. It's NOT the same as the other question mentioned. As I do not need a finally statement...

I have for example the following code:

```
try:
    #dosomething
except TypeError:
    #dosomething -> THIS GIVES A TypeError!

"..."

    #I_want_this_to_be_executed_if_the_previous_commands_are_not_working
```

What can I fill in between the quotation marks to make sure this last command will be executed if the `except TypeError` doesn't work either? (it gives also an TypeError)

I do NOT need a finally statement as it is NOT necessary to be executed ALWAYS, only in case the exception also gives a TypeError...

Comment: For your last edit: an easier way is to put `dosomething` inside functions and do `for func in my_functions: try: func() except SomeException:pass`... I should say  **never** use just `except`. Always specify which exception you want to catch, even if it is `Exception`.

Comment: You can make things conditional in `finally` if the obvious -- nested `try` clauses -- is unacceptable for some reason.

Comment: `try: ... except TypeError: try: ... except TypeError: "..."`…?!

Comment: Another `try..except` inside the `except` clause would be the obvious answer. If you show us more details about what you're trying to do, we may be able to suggest a more succinct alternative.

Comment: @deceze This is what I needed! Thank you very much! I am as you can propably see a beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add: (EDIT: didn't understand the question, the comments are correct)

```
try:
    #dosomething
except TypeError:
    try:
        #What you were going to do
    except TypeError:
        #Handle the second typeError
```